# How to target and display specific database fields for my .Net page

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

I have this simple vb code to pull out each row in the database as requested.

```
dbAD.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(“SELECT * FROM Profile ORDER BY Name ASC", dbConnect)
dbAD.Fill(dbRS, “Profile")
If dbRS.Tables("Profile").Rows.Count > 0 Then
For Each profile As DataRow In dbRS.Tables("Profile").Rows
Response.Write(“Profiles: “ & Profile(“FullName”) & “&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; “ & Profile(“Email”) & “&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; “ & Profile(“Password”) & “&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; “ & Profile(“Academy”) &  “<br />”)
Next
End If
```

My database has the following columns:

FullName,
Email,
Password,
Academy,

Say I wanted to target "Mary Jones" (who appears in FullName column) and just display her information, or just 1 piece of her information, say her Password, do I just have to change the SELECT to something like:

```
SELECT * from Profile WHERE FullName = Mary Jones
```

Or is there much more to it?

Doesn't

```
Eval()
```

have to be used in order for specific data requests from the database?

Comment: Don't forget to use single quotes: `SELECT * from Profile WHERE FullName = 'Mary Jones'`

Comment: Thanks @RicardoPontual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading about basic SQL queries but yes you need to place a `WHERE` condition for a better efficient query like

```
SELECT * from Profile WHERE FullName = 'Mary Jones'
```

Again since you want only `password` field consider getting only that field instead

```
SELECT `password` from Profile WHERE FullName = 'Mary Jones'
```

Though, you can get that specific field at your application end from the `dbRS.Tables("Profile")`